# Pointing multiple .onion domains at one website? Each on separate server?

Tags: network-configuration

Just playing around for fun and knowledge with this. I have a Tor blog, simple informational site that I just toy around with as I enjoy experimenting with Tor technology.

What I would like to do is generate say 3-4 .onion domains. Each one on a SEPARATE server. I would like to point all these domains at one website which will again be on a different server.

I assume install Tor on each server and generate the domains. But how to forward all the domains to the same website that’s on different server?